# Newbie: How to compute a Bernoulli probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How can I solve this: The probability of an error occurs while sending $500$ bytes is $0.25$. What is the probability of an error occurs while sending $7480$ bytes?

It looks like a Bernoulli distribution, so, my approach is to say $p(1) = 0.25$ and compute $P(x \leq \frac{7480}{500})$ .

Comment: Assuming the condition refers to the probability of $\textit {at least}$ one error, then you can use that to back out the probability $p$ that a single byte is transmitted correctly.  From that you can solve the problem.

Comment: To do it roughly, note that you are basically sending $500$ bytes fifteen times.  Since the probability of sending one error free block is $.75$ the probability that all fifteen blocks are error free is $.75^{15}$ so the answer should be quite close to $1-.75^{15}$   I am, of course, assuming that each byte is an independent trial.

Comment: How can I go back to one byte? is it SQRT 500 (0,25)?

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability that one byte is transmitted successfully.  Then, assuming independence, the probability that $500$ bytes are transmitted successfully is $p^{500}$.  But you tell us that that probability is also $.75$ so we have $p^{500}=.75$

Comment: So, the answer for a byte is : https://calculatesquareroot.net/index.php?degree=500&number=0.75

Comment: That gives the value for $p$, yes.

Comment: Forgive me but it's been decades without encountering this. So for a bit, I do a 508 square: https://calculatesquareroot.net/index.php?degree=508&number=0.75

Comment: I have no idea why you would compute that.  Once you have $p$, the answer to the question you posted is $1-p^{7480}\approx .984833$   If you follow the approximation scheme I suggested you would estimate the answer as $1-.75^{15}\approx .98663$ which isn't a bad estimate (keep in mind that the given probabilities are themselves approximations).

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me a lot